# Using Generics to Multiply Integers

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a class called GenericItem (first time using generics), suppose i wanted to multiply two items if they were of the type integer, as you can see I am trying it in the method `returnCounterMultiply`, but it does not allow me to multiply them although i am trying to convert them and also checking if they are of type integer.

```
namespace Components
{
    public class GenericItem<T>
    {
        private T data;
        private T counter;

        public T Data
        {
            get { return data; }
            set { data = value; }
        }

        public GenericItem(){}
        public GenericItem(T _data)
        {
            data = _data;
        }

        public T returnCounterMultiply(T value)
        {
            int c = 0;
            int d = 0;
            if (counter.GetType() == typeof(int) && value.GetType() == typeof(int))
            {
              //cant multiply two of type T, why if i am converting to int?.
               return (T)Convert.ChangeType(counter, typeof(Int32)) * (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(Int32));
            }
            return value;
        }

    }
}
```

I would appreciate some explanation on this as this is the first time I am working on it (this is just a sample class for understanding this [GENERICS INTRO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx) and this [GENERICS CLASSES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx), but still having trouble understanding it.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: This is a bad use of generics. You're trying to perform an operation on a specific type so there is no need for generics.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks, that's fine, i am just trying to learn how someone would go about that. Thank you though, all this will help me.

Comment: @John that i cant apply the * operand to type T, which reading the responses below now it makes more sense. I guess i am trying to figure out when this would be the best to implement.

Comment: @ergwin: Generics is not dynamically-typed. You must know if T is int before returnCounterMultiply() is invoked. If you make returnCounterMultiply() return integer (instead of T) then I think it would make more sense.

Comment: Check my answer - I go in detaul into the syntax errors you have in the multiplication lines. Basically you CAN do what you want, you just screwed up the cast priorities. The code is much easier than you think - just need to keep priorities straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public class GenericItem<T>
{
    private T data;

    public T Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    public GenericItem(){}
    public GenericItem(T _data)
    {
        data = _data;
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> operations =
        new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>()
        {
            { typeof(int), (Func<int, int, int>)((x, y) => x * y) },
            { typeof(string), (Func<string, string, string>)((x, y) => x + " " + y) },
        };

    public T returnCounterMultiply(T value)
    {
        if (operations.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            var operation = (Func<T, T, T>)(operations[typeof(T)]);
            return operation(data, value);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

You just need to define, in the dictionary, one operation per valid types you're going to want to use and it just works without any converting of types (except to cast to the `Func`).

I had these test results:

```
var gii = new GenericItem<int>(42);
var xi = gii.returnCounterMultiply(2);
// xi == 84

var gis = new GenericItem<string>("Foo");
var xs = gis.returnCounterMultiply("Bar");
// xs == "Foo Bar"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, using generics in this case is an overkill.

It would be nice that generic constraints support something like:

```
// T parameter is a type which overloads "+" operator...
where T : +
```

In your concrete case, I would argue you're going in the wrong way. Why don't you just create a class to implement such math operations where properties are typed as `int`?

Generics work better when `T` parameter (or any other parameter, of course...) can be constrained to receive types which have:

- A public parameterless constructor.
- Inherits or implements a class/interface
- You need to constraint that `T` must be a class and not a struct...

When you go into a problem when using generics requires a type conversion, I believe you defeated the point of generics!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what your trying to achieve, but if you have to do it I think you have to use an interface:

```
public interface IMultiplyable<T>
{
    T Multiply(T x);
}

public class Int : IMultiplyable<Int>
{
    private int _data { get; set; }

    public Int(int data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public Int Multiply(Int x)
    {
        return new Int(_data * x._data);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _data.ToString();
    }
}

public class GenericItem<T> where T : IMultiplyable<T>
{
    private T data;
    private T counter;

    public T Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    public GenericItem() { }
    public GenericItem(T _data)
    {
        data = _data;
    }

    public T returnCounterMultiply(T value)
    {
        return Data.Multiply(value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Data.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        var a = new GenericItem<Int>(new Int(4));
        MessageBox.Show(a.returnCounterMultiply(new Int(5)).ToString()); //20
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with generics but with basic C# casting priority:

```
//cant multiply two of type T, why if i am converting to int?.
return
  (T)Convert.ChangeType(counter, typeof(Int32)) 
  *
  (T)Convert.ChangeType(value,typeof(Int32));
```

You do not multiply int but T - and T being a generic type you can only use methods that are ddefined in your generics contraint, which you have none, so no multiply on it.

If you want to multiply int, then do so:

```
  (T) (
     ((Int32)Convert.ChangeType(counter, typeof(Int32)))
     *
     ((Int32)Convert.ChangeType(value,typeof(Int32)))
  );
```

See the difference?

Basically in your code you deal with T in the multiplication, here I deal with Int32. And factually if T is a Int32 (as you tested before in the IF statement) you can just skip the convert and cast:

```
  (T) (
     ((Int32)counter)
     *
     ((Int32)value)
  );
```

Now, generics are a bad example for maths as you can not use operations on generics - sadly. This is an abuse of the concept, but I take it was meant as a learning exercise and thus focused on that part on my answer.

Comment: Thank you @TomTom, that is all i am trying to do, learn about it... why use it? how? when?. All this is helping me a big deal.

Comment: @ergwin I understand. Generally yuou do not do maths like that. Problem is that operators are static methods on a class (like int) and generics do not see them - a lack in the generics concept. TOns of uses still around for them ;) If oyu have classes / Interfaces in the constraints. Still what you want to do CAN be done, and I focused on this part.

Answer (score 0):

I too tried this once and had to find out that there is no pretty way to do it with generics. You cannot do it as generic as in C++.

As an alternative, you may wrap your data types and use a common interface:

```
interface IMathOps
{
    object Value { get; }

    void Add(IMathOps other);
    // other methods for substraction etc.
}

class IntWrapper : IMathOps
{
    public int value;

    public void Add(IMathOps other)
    {
        if(other is IntWrapper)
        {
            this.value += (int)other.Value;
        }
    }

    public object Value { get { return this.value; } }
}

// class FloatWrapper : IMathOps ...
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you should use [where (generic type constraint)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx). So it will give error at compile time if T is not int.

```
public T returnCounterMultiply(T value)  where T : int
{
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;

    return c*d;
}
```

Comment: This isn't the correct syntax. You can only apply the `where` on a method that defines the generic type parameter. Since the class is defining it in this case then your answer won't work.

Comment: Yes.you are correct. We need to apply at class level. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: This beats the use of generics since you restrict the class to a single type.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - You are spot on. If you try to constrain a generic type parameter on a sealed class you get the error "T is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter."